# Why links in iframe on ionic app opens in a different page?

Tags: iframe, ionic-framework

I've got an Iframe in ionic app witch works fine loading different src depending on other things:

```
<iframe src=" " id="frameDemo" ></iframe>
```

The problem occurs when I click in hyperlinks present in the src of the iframe, because in ionic serve --lab opens a new web page over the serve page, in real device android instead it does nothing.

I want the link to be opened in the iframe!

What's the matter?

Thank you.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this isn't possible, as the iframe's contents are decided by the `src` part of your HTML. Clicking a link inside the iframe cannot change the HTML outside the iframe, thus it cannot change the `src`. If you have access to the source of the iframe, you could use JS inside the iframe to make it look as if you're opening a new page in the iframe, but you can't actually open links within an iframe.

Comment: ok, thank you, I'll try  to change the `src` of the iframe with JS. What do you mean with "if you have access to the source"? @Tijimen

Comment: You can't use JS inside the iframe to change the `src` of that iframe. What I mean with 'access to the source', is the contents of the iframe. Are you using the iframe to display a page you can edit, or some external page you have no control over? If you can edit the page inside the iframe, you can use JS to build this page in such a way that it will allow you to "sort of" change to a different page inside the iframe, but if you cannot edit the page inside the iframe, then what you're trying to achieve is impossible (to my knowledge).